# Correct way to write line to file?

Tags: python, file-io

How do I write a line to a file in modern Python? I heard that this is deprecated:

```
print >>f, "hi there"
```

Also, does `"\n"` work on all platforms, or should I use `"\r\n"` on Windows?

Comment: "\n" is not Unix-specific. When the file is opened in text mode (the default), it is translated automatically to the correct line ending for the current platform. Writing "\r\n" would produce "\r\r\n" which is wrong.

Answer (score 1555, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('Hello\n')
```

From The Documentation:

> Do not use `os.linesep` as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single `'\n'` instead, on all platforms.

Some useful reading:

- [The `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)
- [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)

  - `'a'` is for append, or use
  - `'w'` to write with truncation
- [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) (particularly [`os.linesep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.linesep#os.linesep))

Comment: This example is better than the open/close example.  Using `with` is a safer way to remember to close a file.

Comment: I don't have to call `the_file.close()` ?

Comment: no you don't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for

Comment: "text mode (the default)" means `open` with  `"w"`, you still need `os.linesep` with `"wb"`

Comment: @user3226167: That's an interesting point. But why would you open a binary file to write plain text?

Answer (score 1015):

You should use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) function which is available since Python 2.6+

```
from __future__ import print_function  # Only needed for Python 2
print("hi there", file=f)
```

For Python 3 you don't need the `import`, since the  `print()` function is the default.

The alternative in Python 3 would be to use:

```
with open('myfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hi there\n')  # python will convert \n to os.linesep
```

Quoting from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) regarding newlines:

> When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

See also: [Reading and Writing Files - The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: @sorin Why is the first way, using file=f, preferable to the second method using f.write?

Comment: when I am using this method it will remove all of the newlines. How can I fix that to have it written line by line?

Comment: For appending isnt it `open('myfile','a')` instead `open('myfile','w')`?

Comment: My issue with this approach is that it adds a new line character to the last line in the file. Best approach for removing that.

Comment: @BradRuderman That's part of the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) standard for what constitutes a "line" in a text file, i.e. every line in a text file must be terminated by a newline, even the last line.

Comment: A better way would be to encode the string. So, use `open('myfile', 'w', encoding='utf-8')` instead of `open('myfile', 'w')`.

Comment: @I.J. For me, it's just simpler. I use `print()` all the time, and it has a bunch of capabilities that are super useful, like automatically converting its arguments to string. But if I want to be strict, then I'll use `f.write()` to ensure that my code is passing it a string in the correct format, without `print()` possibly applying any pre-processing that I didn't realize.

Comment: @UserYmY "remove all of the newlines"? Huh? How did that happen? You might have been doing something wrong. [I realize I'm replying to an old comment, but just wanted to add this for posterity.]

Comment: @Vishal Sorry, a better way to do what? Encoding isn't really relevant to this topic. And anyway, UTF-8 may be the system default, for example on Linux, so why specify it?

Answer (score 134):

The [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) recommend this way:

```
with open('file_to_write', 'w') as f:
    f.write('file contents\n')
```

So this is the way I usually do it

Statement from [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> It is good practice to use the **'with'** keyword when dealing with file
> objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
> its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
> also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks.

Comment: I don't like this way when I need to nest the `with` inside a loop. That makes me constantly open and close the file as I proceed in my loop. Maybe I am missing something here, or this is really a disadvantage in this particular scenario?

Comment: How about looping within the with?

Answer (score 93):

**Regarding os.linesep:**

Here is an exact unedited Python 2.7.1 interpreter session on Windows:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.linesep
'\r\n'
>>> f = open('myfile','w')
>>> f.write('hi there\n')
>>> f.write('hi there' + os.linesep) # same result as previous line ?????????
>>> f.close()
>>> open('myfile', 'rb').read()
'hi there\r\nhi there\r\r\n'
>>>
```

**On Windows:**

As expected, os.linesep does **NOT** produce the same outcome as `'\n'`. There is no way that it could produce the same outcome. `'hi there' + os.linesep` is equivalent to `'hi there\r\n'`, which is **NOT** equivalent to `'hi there\n'`.

**It's this simple: use `\n` which will be translated automatically to os.linesep.** And it's been that simple ever since the first port of Python to Windows.

There is no point in using os.linesep on non-Windows systems, and it produces wrong results on Windows.

**DO NOT USE os.linesep!**

Comment: great example -- curious if you're an ipython user? nice functions for formatting sessions

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to tell us here. os.linesep will return the line term character (or string) as defined by the operating system. Windows uses \r\n for line endings by default. However, a single \n is recognised.

Using \n is going to give a fully portable OUTPUT but os.linesep is not wrong on windows.

Comment: @Gusdor: The point is that if you explicitly use `os.linesep` in Windows in text mode, the outcome is `\r\r\n` which is wrong. "Windows uses ..." is meaningless. The C runtime library (and hence Python) translate `\n` to `\r\n` on output in text mode. Other software may behave differently. It is NOT the case that all software running on Windows recognises a lone `\n` as a line separator when reading in text mode. Python does. Microsoft's Notepad text editor doesn't.

Comment: @JohnMachin I think I understand what you mean. Worst case scenario is  that you get a double \r in your file. I don't see what the consequence will be. Arguably, if you are writing text mode, you will be reading in it. At which point the extra \r is bloat, but nothing more (only the presence of \n marks a line end)

I write for .Net usually, which lets me pick my line term to use with WriteLine(). Perhaps a similar method on TextIOWrapper would save this confusion.

Comment: Arguably somebody else will be reading it, not you, with some mickey-mouse software that will barf about the extra `\r` ...

Comment: @Gusdor are you coming to python from a different language, where using '\n' results in output of '\n' on window, rather than '\r\n' -- so it lacks the '\r' expected by dumb text editors? As John says, that isn't how Python behaves -- '\n' is automatically replaced by '\r\n', if that is what os.linesep says to do. Hence, explicitly saying `os.linesep` *is* "wrong" here. Its like `Department of Redundancy Department`. Yes you can do it. No, you don't want to.

Comment: I totally agree that it should be explicit.  Never blindly assume things are configured properly unless you set it yourself.  In the case of EOL it is no sweat to just do it.  Send what you know the receiver requires.  `f.write('hi there\n')` for unix and `f.write('hi there\r\n')` for DOS.  I suggest you build an output line like `outline = "Hi There!" + "\r\n"` then simply `f.write(outline)`

Answer (score 63):

I do not think there is a "correct" way.

I would use:

```
with open('myfile', 'a') as f:
    f.write('hi there\n')
```

In memoriam [Tim Toady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: But the OP might want to write additional stuff to the file. Here the file will be closed when the `with` goes out of scope.

Comment: That might want to be `open(..., 'a')` or even `'at'`.

Comment: Erm, yeah. That is the idea of using with. If you want to keep the file open, just call open at the beginning and call close when you are done...

Comment: @mtrw. True. OP was appending.

Comment: As far as python is concerned is RIP Tim Toady - and very very _very_ rightfully so

Comment: I just saw this `Zen of Python is, "There should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it."`  . This explains much of my disappointment with the language.  I have used it a lot for five years plus  but for its libraries and often in spite of the syntax. No inline comments? The  mystifying class structure? Single line only lambdas?

Comment: The `zen of perl` would be a bit of an oxymoron.

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3 it is a function, but in Python 2 you can add this to the top of the source file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then you do

```
print("hi there", file=f)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. So much easier to maintain than adding a newline character into the string.

Answer (score 20):

Since 3.5 you can also use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text) for that purpose:

> `Path.write_text(data, encoding=None, errors=None)`
>
> Open the file pointed to in text mode, write data to it, and close the file:

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path('textfile.txt').write_text('content')
```

Comment: Underappreciated answer. It's the most concise. All other answers forget that `write` on a file object may write a **part** of its argument.

Answer (score 18):

If you are writing a lot of data and speed is a concern you should probably go with `f.write(...)`. I did a quick speed comparison and it was considerably faster than `print(..., file=f)` when performing a large number of writes.

```
import time    

start = start = time.time()
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in range(10000000):
        # print('This is a speed test', file=f)
        # f.write('This is a speed test\n')
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

On average `write` finished in 2.45s on my machine, whereas `print` took about 4 times as long (9.76s). That being said, in most real-world scenarios this will not be an issue.

If you choose to go with `print(..., file=f)` you will probably find that you'll want to suppress the newline from time to time, or replace it with something else. This can be done by setting the optional `end` parameter, e.g.;

```
with open("test", 'w') as f:
    print('Foo1,', file=f, end='')
    print('Foo2,', file=f, end='')
    print('Foo3', file=f)
```

Whichever way you choose I'd suggest using `with` since it makes the code much easier to read.

**Update**: This difference in performance is explained by the fact that `write` is highly buffered and returns before any writes to disk actually take place (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857052/why-is-printing-to-stdout-so-slow-can-it-be-sped-up)), whereas `print` (probably) uses line buffering. A simple test for this would be to check performance for long writes as well, where the disadvantages (in terms of speed) for line buffering would be less pronounced.

```
start = start = time.time()
long_line = 'This is a speed test' * 100
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in range(1000000):
        # print(long_line, file=f)
        # f.write(long_line + '\n')
end = time.time()

print(end - start, "s")
```

The performance difference now becomes much less pronounced, with an average time of 2.20s for `write` and 3.10s for `print`. If you need to concatenate a bunch of strings to get this loooong line performance will suffer, so use-cases where `print` would be more efficient are a bit rare.

Comment: There is no need to call `print()` multiple times for each line, you can input each line as a positional argument and specify a newline delimiter using `print(line1, line2, ... sep="\n")`. This makes only one write call.

Answer (score 8):

When you said Line it means some serialized characters which are ended to '\n' characters. Line should be last at some point so we should consider '\n' at the end of each line. Here is solution:

```
with open('YOURFILE.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write("Hello")
```

in append mode after each write the cursor move to new line, if you want to use `w` mode you should add `\n` characters at the end of the `write()` function:

```
the_file.write("Hello\n")
```

Comment: "in append mode after each write the cursor move to new line" – no it's not.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid using `write()` or `writelines()` and joining the strings with a newline yourself, you can pass all of your lines to `print()`, and the newline delimiter and your file handle as keyword arguments. This snippet assumes your strings do not have trailing newlines.

```py
print(line1, line2, sep="\n", file=f)
```

You don't need to put a special newline character is needed at the end, because `print()` does that for you.

If you have an arbitrary number of lines in a list, you can use list expansion to pass them all to `print()`.

```py
lines = ["The Quick Brown Fox", "Lorem Ipsum"]
print(*lines, sep="\n", file=f)
```

It is OK to use `"\n"` as the separator on Windows, because `print()` will also automatically convert it to a Windows CRLF newline (`"\r\n"`).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to insert items in a list with a format per line, a way to start could be:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    for item in items:
        the_file.write(f"{item}\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

One can also use the `io` module as in:

```
import io
my_string = "hi there"

with io.open("output_file.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(my_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need to write new lines a lot, I define a lambda that uses a `print` function:

```
out = open(file_name, 'w')
fwl = lambda *x, **y: print(*x, **y, file=out) # FileWriteLine
fwl('Hi')
```

This approach has the benefit that it can utilize all the features that are available with the `print` function.

**Update:** As is mentioned by [Georgy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851470/georgy) in the comment section, it is possible to improve this idea further with the `partial` function:

```
from functools import partial
fwl = partial(print, file=out)
```

IMHO, this is a more functional and less cryptic approach.

Comment: Or another (probably cleaner) way to write this: `from functools import partial; fwl = partial(print, file=out)`.

Comment: @Georgy Your approach is so good that it can be given as a new answer.

Comment: The idea is the same as yours, just implementation is a bit different. If you want, you can add it in an edit to your answer. I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

To write text in a file in the flask can be used:

```
filehandle = open("text.txt", "w")
filebuffer = ["hi","welcome","yes yes welcome"]
filehandle.writelines(filebuffer)
filehandle.close()
```

Comment: It is always more advisable to write to a file with a `with open('file_to_write', 'w') as f:` statement. It's much easier to make sure that file will not be left open if someone accidentally wrote something in between that would result in not having an explicit `close()` call

Comment: writelines does not write each item of the iterable in a new line but rather concatenates all the items into one line. The output of your code will be a file with a single line:
"hiwelcomeyes yes welcome"

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `filewriter`

`pip install filewriter`

```
from filewriter import Writer

Writer(filename='my_file', ext='txt') << ["row 1 hi there", "row 2"]
```

Writes into `my_file.txt`

Takes an iterable or an object with `__str__` support.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('sample.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello')
    f.write('\n')
```

Insert *f.write('\n')* at the end

Answer (score -2):

since others have answered how to do it, I'll answer how it happens line by line.

```
with FileOpenerCM('file.txt') as fp: # is equal to "with open('file.txt') as fp:"
      fp.write('dummy text')
```

this is a so-called `context manager`, anything that comes with a `with` block is a context manager. so let's see how this happens under the hood.

```
class FileOpenerCM:
     def __init__(self, file, mode='w'):
         self.file = open(file, mode)
      
     def __enter__(self):
          return self.file
      
     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
         self.file.close()
```

the first method `__init__` is (as you all know) the initialization method of an object. whenever an object is created `obj.__init__` is definitely called. and that's the place where you put your all the init kinda code.

the second method `__enter__` is a bit interesting. some of you might not have seen it because it is a specific method for context managers. what it returns is the value to be assigned to the variable after the `as` keyword. in our case, `fp`.

the last method is the method to run after an error is captured or if the code exits the with block. `exc_type`, `exc_value`, `exc_traceback` variables are the variables that hold the values of the errors that occurred inside with block. for example,

```
exc_type: TypeError
exc_value: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str
exc_traceback: <traceback object at 0x6af8ee10bc4d>
```

from the first two variables, you can get info enough info about the error. honestly, I don't know the use of the third variable, but for me, the first two are enough. if you want to do more research on context managers surely you can do it and note that writing classes are not the only way to write context managers. with [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) you can write context managers through functions(actually generators) as well. it's totally up to you to have a look at it. you can surely try
generator functions with contextlib but as I see classes are much cleaner.