# write() versus writelines() and concatenated strings

Tags: python, string, file-io, python-2.x

So I'm learning Python. I am going through the lessons and ran into a problem where I had to condense a great many `target.write()` into a single `write()`, while having a `"\n"` between each user input variable(the object of `write()`).

I came up with:

```
nl = "\n"
lines = line1, nl, line2, nl, line3, nl
textdoc.writelines(lines)
```

If I try to do:

```
textdoc.write(lines)
```

I get an error. But if I type:

```
textdoc.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + ....)
```

Then it works fine. Why am I unable to use a string for a newline in `write()` but I can use it in `writelines()`?

Python 2.7

Comment: `lines` is not a string in your example. It is a tuple consisting of six strings.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

- `writelines` expects an iterable of strings
- `write` expects a single string.

`line1 + "\n" + line2` merges those strings together into a single string before passing it to `write`.

Note that if you have many lines, you may want to use `"\n".join(list_of_lines)`.

Comment: Why should you use `write` instead of `writelines` if you have many lines? Writelines could be better performing as it doesn't have to create a temporary concatenated string, just iterating over the lines.

Comment: @hBy2Py: exactly the opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165711/281545

Comment: A single string is also an iterable in Python

Answer (score 154):

*Why am I unable to use a string for a newline in write() but I can use it in writelines()?*

The idea is the following: if you want to write a single string you can do this with `write()`. If you have a sequence of strings you can write them all using `writelines()`.

`write(arg)` expects a string as argument and writes it to the file. If you provide a list of strings, it will raise an exception (by the way, show errors to us!).

`writelines(arg)` expects an iterable as argument (an iterable object can be a tuple, a list, a string, or an iterator in the most general sense). Each item contained in the iterator is expected to be a string. A tuple of strings is what you provided, so things worked.

The nature of the string(s) does not matter to both of the functions, i.e. they just write to the file whatever you provide them. The interesting part is that `writelines()` does not add newline characters on its own, so the method name can actually be quite confusing. It actually behaves like an imaginary method called `write_all_of_these_strings(sequence)`.

What follows is an idiomatic way in Python to write a list of strings to a file while keeping each string in its own line:

```
lines = ['line1', 'line2']
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

This takes care of closing the file for you. The construct `'\n'.join(lines)` concatenates (connects) the strings in the list `lines` and uses the character '\n' as glue. It is more efficient than using the `+` operator.

Starting from the same `lines` sequence, ending up with the same output, but using `writelines()`:

```
lines = ['line1', 'line2']
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines("%s\n" % l for l in lines)
```

This makes use of a generator expression and dynamically creates newline-terminated strings. `writelines()` iterates over this sequence of strings and writes every item.

**Edit: Another point you should be aware of:**

`write()` and `readlines()` existed before `writelines()` was introduced. `writelines()` was introduced later as a counterpart of `readlines()`, so that one could easily write the file content that was just read via `readlines()`:

```
outfile.writelines(infile.readlines())
```

Really, this is the main reason why `writelines` has such a confusing name. Also, today, we do not really want to use this method anymore. `readlines()` reads the entire file to the memory of your machine before `writelines()` starts to write the data. First of all, this may waste time. Why not start writing parts of data while reading other parts? But, most importantly, this approach can be very memory consuming. In an extreme scenario, where the input file is larger than the memory of your machine, this approach won't even work. The solution to this problem is to use iterators only. A working example:

```
with open('inputfile') as infile:
    with open('outputfile') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

This reads the input file line by line. As soon as one line is read, this line is written to the output file. Schematically spoken, there always is only one single line in memory (compared to the entire file content being in memory in case of the readlines/writelines approach).

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. Based on your explanation I would assume that f.writelines() would be more useful in generating a log file and f.write() is more useful for single or multiple edits in a particular or multiple files?

Comment: @AbeLinkon: I would not support this conclusion. `write()` and `writelines()` are basically equivalent and their usage also is a question of personal taste. However, it is important to note that for an extremely long list of strings (called `lines`) it is less efficient to write `f.write('\n'.join(lines))` than `for l in line: f.write('%s\n' % l)`. In the first case, an entirely new and very long string is created in memory before writing it. In the second case the data is written piece-wise.

Comment: f.write('\n'.join(lines))  did not add the last nl when I ran it.

Comment: @Jim: this is to be expected, `'s'.join(iterable)` only fills the gaps with 's', it does not add prefix/suffix.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't do `outf.writelines(inf.readlines())` but rather `outf.writelines(inf)`. The function we don't want to use anymore is `readlines()` not `writelines()`.

Comment: @moooeeeep: while nothing is wrong with the functionality/implementation of `writelines()`, its semantics are, as explained, less than ideal. This is why I have never used it. And I never missed it.

Comment: @AbeLinkon - maybe you should consider to accept this answer, it is clearly better than the one you originally accepted

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, this would be clearer with a trailing newline: ``f.write('\n'.join(lines) + '\n')`` so that it matches ``f.writelines("%s\n" % l for l in lines)`` in the second snippet

Answer (score -6):

Actually, I think the problem is that your variable "lines" is bad. You defined lines as a tuple, but I believe that write() requires a string. All you have to change is your commas into pluses (+).

```
nl = "\n"
lines = line1+nl+line2+nl+line3+nl
textdoc.writelines(lines)
```

should work.

Answer (score -7):

Exercise 16 from Zed Shaw's book? You can use escape characters as follows:

```
paragraph1 = "%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (line1, line2, line3)
target.write(paragraph1)
target.close()
```

Comment: Very weak solution. If you wanted to concatenate several lines in this manner, you should do it like this: `" \n ".join((line1, line2, line3))`.

Answer (score -8):

if you just want to save and load a list try [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Pickle saving:

```
with open("yourFile","wb")as file:
 pickle.dump(YourList,file)
```

and loading:

```
with open("yourFile","rb")as file:
 YourList=pickle.load(file)
```