# Writing on new lines to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

The section of coding I've written is as such:

```
thing=9
text_file=open("something.txt", "a")
text_file.write("\n", str(thing))
text_file.close()
```

This always returns the error Type error: "write" only takes 1 argument. 2 given.
What I'm trying to do is that each time I run this code it writes on a new line rather than the same line. Right now, if this doesn't work, I'm a bit confused how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: DUPLICATED:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377473/python-write-versus-writelines-and-concatenated-strings

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter is correct in saying:

```
"write" only takes 1 argument. 2 given
```

Python's file methods are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

All you need to be doing is concatenating your string with the newline character. You can do so by replacing:

```
text_file.write("\n", str(thing))
```

with:

```
text_file.write("\n" + str(thing))
```

This will write an empty line before writing out what you want. This might not be what you are looking for. Instead you can do:

```
text_file.write(str(thing) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline to the end<sup>1</sup> of the string with the `+` operator:

```
text_file.write(str(thing) + "\n")
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note: If you add it to the front, you will get a blank line at the top of your file, which may not be what you want.</sub>