# TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument

Tags: python, file, iterable

I got the following error in my python code:

```
     TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument
```

I know it's error submited before but I can't got my answer . here is my code :

```
 def Normaliaze(dataset):    
      final_list=[]
      twoCol = [ item[0:2] for item in dataset]
      labels = [ item[2] for item in dataset]
      twoColData = preprocessing.scale(float64(twoCol ))

      for x,y in itertools.izip(twoColData,labels):
         temp =[]
         temp.append(x[0])
         temp.append(x[1])
         temp.append(y)
         final_list.append(temp)

      caving = open('/home/nima/Desktop/ramin-ML-Project/caving.txt','w')

      for item in final_list:
         if item[2] == 'caving':            
             caving.writelines(item[0])
             caving.writelines('\t')
             caving.writelines(item[1])
             caving.writelines('\n')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `writelines()` but passing in *one item at a time*; `file.writelines()` expects an iterable (something producing a sequence of 0 or more values) instead.

Use `file.writeline()` (singular) instead, or even better, just `file.write()`:

```
caving.write(item[0])
caving.write('\t')
caving.write(item[1])
caving.write('\n')
```

If you are writing a Tab-separate file, you might want to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead:

```
import csv

def normalize(dataset):    
    twoCol = [item[:2] for item in dataset]
    labels = [item[2] for item in dataset]
    twoColData = preprocessing.scale(float64(twoCol))

    with open('/home/nima/Desktop/ramin-ML-Project/caving.txt', 'wb') as caving:
        writer = csv.writer(caving, delimiter='\t')

        for data, label in itertools.izip(twoColData, labels):
            if label == 'caving':
                writer.writerow(data)
```

This produces the same output, but with less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

For strings you should write(), while for a sequence of strings you can use writelines(). See the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377473/python-write-versus-writelines-and-concatenated-strings). For instance, you try to write the sting '\t' with writeline().