# Write each element of a list on a newline on a text file in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, writefile

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371987/python-how-to-write-a-list-of-strings-on-separate-lines-but-withot-a-blank-line), I am trying to **write each element of a list** (`mylist`) **on a newline on a text file** (`text.txt`).

So, for example, the list

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'ccc', 'dd', 'eeee', 'f', 'ggg']
```

should be written on the `text.txt` like so

```
a
b
ccc
dd
eeee
f
ggg
```

I have tried this:

```
filename = 'text.txt'

with open(filename, mode="wb") as outfile:  # also, tried mode="rb"
    for s in mylist:
        outfile.write("%s\n" % s)
```

which creates the text file but then gives an error; either a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` or `io.UnsupportedOperation: write` depending on the `mode` I use.

Any ideas please, along with a short explanation of what I am doing wrong will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing text, you shouldn't use the "b" mode:

```
with open(filename, mode="w") as outfile: 
    # Here ---------------^
```