# How to read the text file format and write the same in to excel file as mentioned in the below format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read the data from the text file below and write it to an Excel sheet as explained further

[image]

The text file is formatted with each value on a new line.

The Excel file should have

- **'adobe'** in row 0, column 1
- **IE11.o** to row 0, column 2
- **32** to row 0, column 3
- **flash** to row 1, column 1
- **IE8.0** to row 1, column 2
- **24** to row 1, column 3

and so on for many rows

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free code writing service. Please try something and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Sure and Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to [read the text file, line by line, into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list). Then you can either [export your data as a .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/python-write-to-csv-line-by-line) which excel can read, or directly as an excel file using [a library like Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/).

For example this code does what you've asked for, if you're happy to produce a .csv instead of an excel file:

```
fname = "" #path to file
csvname = "" #path to output csv

with open(fname) as f: #reads the file
    content = f.readlines() #writes lines to list
content = [x.strip() for x in content] #removes blank list values

names = content[0::3] #builds list of names
IEs = content[1::3] #builds list of IEs
numbers = content[2::3] #builds list of numbers

with open(csvname) as file: #creates csv file
    for i in range(len(content)/3): #runs through rows
        file.write(names[i]+","+IEs[i]+","+numbers[i]) #writing data to rows
        file.write('\n') #ends line after each row
```