# Creating text files in Python

Tags: python, file

Is it possible to create a variable in which I can store a list of products instead of using "lines" variable. when creating a text file

```
#creating a textfile 

text_file= open("productlist.txt", "w")

lines = ("Bed","\n","Couch","\n","Mirror","\n","Television","\n"
         "Tables","\n","Radio")


text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()

text_file = open("productlist.txt")
print(text_file.read())
text_file.close()
```

Comment: you mean `lines = text_file.readlines()` maybe ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, I want to know if I can be able to use another variable when creating this list                                                           
lines = ("Bed","\n","Couch","\n","Mirror","\n","Television","\n""Tables","\n","Radio")

Comment: I really don't know what you mean. You can create as many variables as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will try and see if it comes alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing each line, and the line breaks, individually using `writelines`, you can create a single string containing all the lines and the line breaks, and `write` that.

In order to create the combined string from a list of items, you can use `join`.

```
products = ["Bed", "Couch", "Mirror", "Television", "Tables", "Radio"]
text_file.write("\n".join(products))
```

(Note that `(a, b, c)` creates a tuple, while `[a, b, c]` creates a list. You may want to learn about the differences, but in this case it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is to not write a line break "\n" in there every time, right? Just throw your code into a loop:

```
#Create text file
text_file = open("productlist.txt", "w")

#Enter list of products
products = ["Bed", "Couch", "Mirror", "Television", "Tables", "Radio"] #Formerly "lines" variable

#Enter each product on a new line
for product in products:
    text_file.writelines(product)
    text_file.writelines('\n')

#Close text file for writing
text_file.close()

#Open text file for reading
text_file = open("productlist.txt")
print(text_file.read())

#Close text file
text_file.close()
```

If you ever decide you want to append to your document rather than overwrite it every time, just change
    text_file= open("productlist.txt", "w")
to
    text_file= open("productlist.txt", "a")

If a text document isn't the best format for your list, you might consider [exporting to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/python-write-to-csv-line-by-line) (which you can open in an excel spreadsheet)

Comment: this makes so much sense and its much more readable, is there a difference when using (  and [  when assigning values to a variable.

Comment: Yes, @mkrieger1 explains below in his answer that using (products) will result in a tuple whereas [products] will result in a list. I would do a google search and learn the difference

Comment: Why not use `with open()` btw ?

Comment: I have the below code and Im trying to remove a line from the above productlist.txt file but the problem is I still see everything and nothing has been removed `import sys
f=open("productlist.txt", "r")
lines= f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
f.close()
del lines[2]
f=open("productlist.txt", "r")
lines= f.read()
print(lines)
f.close()`