# Beautifulsoup python3 Howlongtobeat.com extracting name (and other elements)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to figure out how to extract the name of the game through beautifulsoup

I think i having a problem with the HTML aspect of it

here what I have so far:

```
from requests import get

url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=38050'

response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

game_length = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='game_times')

length = (game_length[-1].find_all({'li': '    short time_100 shadow_box'})[-1].contents[3].get_text())

print(length)

game_name = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='profile_header_game')

game = (game_name[].find({"profile_header shadow_text"})[].contents[].get_text())

print(game)
```

I'm getting the length but not the game name why?

for print(length) prints:

```
31 Hours
```

but for print(game) prints:

> > > game_name = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='profile_header_game')
> > >
> > > game = (game_name[].find({"profile_header shadow_text"})[].contents[].get_text())
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           game = (game_name[].find({"profile_header shadow_text"})[].contents[].get_text())
> > >                             ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >
> > > print(game)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'game' is not defined

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few syntax issues in your code. Here is a corrected version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=38050'
response = requests.get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
game_times_tag = html_soup.find('div', class_='game_times')

game_time_list = []
for li_tag in game_times_tag.find_all('li'):
    title = li_tag.find('h5').text.strip()
    play_time = li_tag.find('div').text.strip()

    game_time_list.append((title, play_time))

for game_time in game_time_list:
    print(game_time)

profile_header_tag = html_soup.find("div", {"class": "profile_header shadow_text"})
game_name = profile_header_tag.text.strip()
print(game_name)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps but I am trying to get the game name as well any tips?

looking to make a spreadsheet out of the data as well, how can I extract the data in a "cleaner" format?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, it looks like I initially forgot to add the game name in the code! I updated my answer to fix that.

If you want to extract the data to a spreadsheet, you could just write the data to a CSV file, which can be opened easily with a spritesheet editor (Excel, ...). Consider checking out this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37290105/7663649) about CSV writers if you want more details.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this code (even before editing) can you confirm that this should work?

I'm getting an this error

     **game_time_list.append((title, play_time))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    game_time_list.append((title, play_time))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent**

Game Name works perfectly

Comment: It looks like this part of the code is not indented properly. Make sure that the whitespace before the line contains exactly 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks I'm going to try that! I  was wondering to (I'm very new to all this) I am copying and pasting the code into ubuntu command console is there a better way (a program maybe) to compile the code? (this may also be my issue but am not sure)

Comment: Yes, you are right! An easier way is to create a Python file, for example "script.py". You can then paste the code inside the file and run it in your command console using `python script.py`.

Answer (score 0):

shorter version

```
game_length = html_soup.select('div.game_times li div')[-1].text
game_name = html_soup.select('div.profile_header')[0].text
developer = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nDeveloper:\n')[0].next_sibling
```

Comment: can you tell me how I can get the Developer from the page?

Comment: should be goood