# How to write data to csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

How to write data to csv file in Python? I have csv file with data which have to be transform.

I do it in this way:

```
import csv

with open('bookcat.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    if row:
        id = row[0].strip()
        categories = row[1:]
        for cat in categories:
            cat = cat.strip()
            if cat:
                print("%s\t%s" % (id, cat))
```

`id` and `cat` have to be write to `csv` file. 
Before executed it I have csv file which looks like:

```
    1,,,,,,,,201,202,,204,,206,207,208,,301,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,605,606,,
    2,,,,,,,,201,,,204,205,,,,209,301,,,304,,402,,,405,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,604,,,,
    3,,,,,,,,201,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,506,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    4,,,,,,,,,,,204,,206,,208,209,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    5,,,,,,,,201,,,204,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Now, after executed my code in Python it looks like:

```
    1   201
    1   202
    1   204
    1   206
    1   207
    1   208
    1   301
    1   605
    1   606
    2   201
    2   204
    2   205
    2   209
    2   301
    2   304
```

And i want to write it to csv file with delimiter ; or , .

Comment: Please don’t share code/data as images. Can you explain what the issue is? Have you read the csv docs?

Comment: hello, this image shosw how to data should looks like in the csv file which I have to create.

Comment: Right, yes, I’m not sure how that relates to my comment though.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. It is better now? My question is:how to save this data to a csv file?

Comment: I was looking for something more specific. What have you tried? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Also, this question is most likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37289951/11301900.

Comment: I added another information abuout my problem. I tried to do it like in the link from you but I failed,I dont know where and how to save data to a csv file with appriopriate delimiter.

Comment: _I tried to do it like in the link from you but I failed,I dont know where and how to save data to a csv file with appriopriate delimiter._ **Please be more specific**. _with appriopriate delimiter_ That should be trivial, have you read the docs for the csv module?  As an aside, why do you want to use a semicolon as the delimiter, instead of a comma?

Comment: Ok, delimiter is not important. Yes i read it and I can write one line to csv file but i cant write my transformed data in Python from csv file to another csv file.

Comment: _I can write one line to csv file but i cant write my transformed data in Python from csv file to another csv file._ That isn't any more specific, detailed, or clear than your previous comment.

Comment: import csv
with open('bookcat.csv') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            id = row[0].strip()
            writer.writerow(id)
            categories = row[1:]
            for cat in categories:
                cat = cat.strip()
                if cat:
                   print("%s\t%s" % (id, cat))
                writer.writerow(cat)

Comment: I tried code like this but it didnt work

Comment: What does _it didnt work_ mean, exactly? Don't share code or anything like that in the comments, it's difficult to read.

Comment: Where should I save the data after transforming them in the code so that in the csv file the row looks like this: id, cat?

Comment: That's even more vague... Did you take a look at the other question I linked?

Comment: Yes i did it but in this question someone didnt transform data from csv. In my example i have csv file where each row contains a book identifier and several category identifiers and I want to change it so that each row has a book identifier and a category identifier.

Comment: Your situation isn't exactly identical to that other question, but it doesn't matter, the way in which you write the output to a CSV file is the same.

Comment: yes, my problem is where and how to save the data to receive the file in the format that is right for me. If it were to write to the csv file without this data transformation then this would not be this question.

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, what I meant is that the "write to CSV" part of your program will follow the same general design as the solutions presented in that other question. At this point I would strongly recommend taking a step back, and trying to break down this entire problem/program on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
import csv
with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
    writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
    writer.writerow([2, "Tim Berners-Lee", "World Wide Web"])
    writer.writerow([3, "Guido van Rossum", "Python Programming"])
```

Output

```
SN,Name,Contribution
1,Linus Torvalds,Linux Kernel
2,Tim Berners-Lee,World Wide Web
3,Guido van Rossum,Python Programming
```