# Looking up value of one csv file in another csv file, if value found write the values into a another csv

Tags: python, csv

a.csv

```
number  address 
------  ------- 
1
2
3
4 
5
```

b.csv

```
number    address1  address2
------    --------  --------
2          abc      def
3          abc1     def1
4          abc2     def2
```

Numbers 2 , 3 and 4 found in both a and b.csv. So I want the final output in the a.csv file itself like below:

```
number    address 
------    -------
1
2         abc def
3         abc1 def1
4         abc2 def2
5
```

Code I tried:

```
nos = []
with open("a.csv", "r") as# Skip the first line
  f.readline()
  for line in f:
  nos.append(int(line.strip("\n")))

with open("b.csv", "r") as f:

  f.readline()
  for line in f:
    if int(line.split(",")[1]) in nos:
```

How to write into a.csv file itself back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python write to CSV line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/python-write-to-csv-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0):

To write a csv file you can use the csv library:

```
import csv

...
with open('c.csv', mode='w') as new_file:
    writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(line.split(','))
```

EDIT:

```
with open('b.csv', 'r') as b, open('c.csv', 'w') as c:
    b = b.readline()
    writer = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in b:
        if int(line.split(',')[1]) in nos:
            writer.writerow(line.split(','))
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/how-to-write-to-a-csv-line-by-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)

EDIT:

As shown in the top answer, you actually already have line of csv in your `line` variable. You could therefore just do this:

```
with open('b.csv', 'r') as b, open('c.csv', 'w') as c:
    b = b.readline()
    for line in b:
        if int(line.split(',')[1]) in nos:
            c.write(line)
            c.write('\n')
```

Comment: maybe better to put the for loop inside the second `with open()`

Comment: You mean like below:

Comment: with open("b.csv", "r") as f:

  f.readline()
  for line in f:, mode='w') as new_file:
    if int(line.split(",")[1]) in nos: with open('a.csv'    mode='w') as new_file:    like this ?

Comment: Thank you! Will it write the whole row values from b.csv to c.scv ? As b.csv have more than 1 column. I need the whole row values from b.csv to c.csv.

Comment: I ended up having below error with the above code while writing into a new line. c.write(line)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Sorry changed the wb to a w