# selenium with python how to get the result that products available in this category or not

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I want to get the number of products in the children categories available or not but I cannot get this.
My code is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.1/chromedriver.exe')

# Windows Maximize
driver.maximize_window()
# opening website URL
driver.get("http://esindbaad.com/")
# checking catagories one bye one
# Food & Grocery (Beverages)
food = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='head-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")
Beverages = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='head-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li/a")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(food).move_to_element(Beverages).click().perform()
driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0,900)")
# Return back to home page
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script ( "window.history.go(-1)" )
# Food & Grocery (fruits)
food = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='head-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")
fruits = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='head-wrapper']/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li/a")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(food).move_to_element(fruits).click().perform()
driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0,900)")
# Return back to home page
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script ( "window.history.go(-1)" )
```

In this I want to get the result that how many products are available in the Food & Grocery (Beverages) and like other fields.

Comment: Hi Usman, I am not sure about Selenium, but maybe part of your solution could be in other scraper libraries, e.g. beautiful soup. I also use import requests & 
import re, with re.findall, and requests.get

Comment: hi bro i tried but it gives me an error like ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'

Comment: Hi Usman you can pip install Beautiful Soup see guides  [https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) ,  and pip install requests [https://pypi.org/project/requests/](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of products on a one page you should get the list of them and measure its length.

Here:
1 I go to the main page
2 Click Food & Grocery
3. Get the products number with a unique locator:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get('https://esindbaad.com/')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".item-vertical.with-sub-menu.hover>a[href*='cat1_id=5&cat2_id=0&cat3_id=0']").click()  # clicking the food & grocery category
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".products-list>.product-layout")))
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".products-list>.product-layout")
length = len(cards)
print(length)
driver.quit()
```

Get the output: 15.
The main solution for your question are these two rows:

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".products-list>.product-layout")
length = len(cards)
```

`find_elements_by_css_selector` is used to find a list of elements.
Other then that, you do not have to set same implicit wait many times. Set it only in the beginning and it will be applied.

Your code has other problems, but I abstract away from them (locators, windows handling etc).

Comment: bro if I want to make a CVs or xl file of the output then which scenario is best

Comment: csv would be easier as for me. I'll appreciate upvote of my answer.

Comment: thanks, bro, and kindly tell me how I can convert my all output of many pages into CSV

Comment: your guides really useful for me and am really happy for solving my problem

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/how-to-write-to-a-csv-line-by-line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232102/discussion-between-usman-riaz-nain-and-vitaliis).