# Extract the csv files from the sub directory python

Tags: python, csv, path, export-to-csv

I have the local path (parent directory) and I would like to extract only the paths that contain csv and saves them in a csv file.

What I tried so far?

```
import os

directory = os.path.join("path/to/dir","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith(".csv"): 
            f=open(file, 'r')
            f.close()
```

This does not extract all csv and saves it. How do I do that?

Comment: import csv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289951/how-to-write-to-a-csv-line-by-line

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Doesn't save as csv

Comment: Well, what do you want in your CSV? Show your desired output as text.

Comment: The folder path that contains the list of csv files

Comment: From your script, it seems you only open the CSV file and close it.
I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't really need to use os.walk function.
Instead glob has the recursive functionality that can get you exactly what you want.

```
from glob import glob
import csv
import os

parent_directory = "/parent/directory/"
save_file = "/save/directory/csv_of_csvs.csv"
csv_files_list = glob(pathname=parent_directory + "**/*.csv", recursive=True)
folder_list = [os.path.dirname(i) for i in csv_files_list]
folder_list = set(folder_list)

with open(save_file, 'w', newline ='') as csv_file:
    write = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for i in folder_list:
        write.writerow([i])
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you only want to log the path of CSV files in the folder.

This should do, for all the recursive paths:

```py
import os

directory = os.path.join("path/to/dir","path")

with open("all_files.csv", "w") as f:
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory): 
        for file in files: 
            if file.endswith(".csv"): 
                f.write(f"{root}/{file}")
```

In case you want one CSV file per directory:

```py
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory): 
    with open(f"{root}/files.csv", "w") as f:
        for file in files: 
            if file.endswith(".csv"): 
                f.write(f"{root}/{file}")
```