# Python2 writelines() called with string

Tags: python

When I use `f.writelines('aaa')` in both Python2 and Python3, the string `aaa` is written to the file, but what I expect is three separate lines of `a`.

Here is the document of `writelines`:

```
writelines(sequence_of_strings) -> None.  Write the strings to the file.

Note that newlines are not added.  The sequence can be any iterable object 
producing strings. This is equivalent to calling write() for each string.
```

Please note that it accepts any iterable and `str` **is** iterable, so why instead of writing a line for each item in the string, `writelines()` simply writes a single string?

Should I need to use `f.writelines(list('aaa'))` to get the desired result?

I wonder whether this is a deliberately consideration or simply a novel bug.

Comment: Your analysis and expectation assume that `writelines` calls `list(...)` on the string that is given, isn't it?

Comment: While the question itself is not exactly a duplicate, you may find this answer interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377575/1453822

Comment: _Note that newlines are not added._ Does that tell you anything?

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes.

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh I figure out. 3 ``a`` without newline is just ``aaa``.

Comment: Folks, sorry first for asking such a stupid question. If I have known that earlier but the name of ``writelines`` makes me believe that it can turn a sequence of strings into a bunch of lines. Now I am clear about the nature of ``writelines``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

> ```
> writelines(lines)
> ```
>
> Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators are not added, so
>   it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a line separator at
>   the end.

Example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(['a\n','a\n','a\n'])
```

Output:

```
a
a
a
```

Please note that the line separator `\n` is part of each string.

Comment: What would be the output of `f.writelines('a\na\na')` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace you probably knew the answer before you posted the comment, and so do/did I... the output will be the same, also it would be the same as `f.write('a\na\na')`. Or should I say 'similar' as your example does not have a `\n` (nor does my example in this comment) so technically the code in my answer has 1 more `\n` at the end.

Comment: Why would you ever do that? If you had newlines in a string, you would just write the string using `f.write`.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge... you are correct by asking that, and to be honest I wouldn't, I am only answering the OP question, who did not include line separators, while the documentation clearly states that the `.writelines()` does not add them, hence this answer.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo ah my bad. I should have @DeepSpace 'd there. I was asking why we would ever do `f.writelines('a\na\na')`

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge This whole question is hypothetical and so was my   bite

Comment: @DeepSpace well... maybe not hypothetical, if you are creating a generic function in your code which can take lists as well as strings to write to file (albeit the elements of the list as well as the string must have a line separator), then you could use writelines() in your function to cater for both easily... right ?

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Fair enough, I guess