# No display in Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run this code the Python Console from PyCharm doesn't show anything.

```
folder = open("meu_arquivo.txt", 'w' )

my_list = []

i = 0
while i < 4:
    a = int(input("numero: "))
    my_list.append(a)
    i += 1
print(my_list)
folder.writelines(str(my_list))

folder.close()

folder = open("meu_arquivo.txt", 'r')
folder.readlines()
```

Comment: try restarting the pycharm

Comment: Maybe, your file is too large?

Comment: You have to input something.

Comment: stop using pycharm and switch to Spyder. I had a lot of issue with pycharm.

Comment: [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) takes a list not a str as argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write() versus writelines() and concatenated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377473/write-versus-writelines-and-concatenated-strings)