# Creating a list from another list - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to create a program where the user inputs a list of strings, each one in a separate line. I want to be able to be able to return, for example, the third word in the second line. The input below would then return "blue".

```
input_string("""The cat in the hat 
Red fish blue fish """)
```

Currently I have this:

```
def input_string(input):
    words = input.split('\n')
```

So I can output a certain line using words[n], but how do output a specific word in a specific line? I've been trying to implement being able to type words[1][2] but my attempts at creating a multidimensional array have failed.

I've been trying to split each words[n] for a few hours now and google hasn't helped. I apologize if this is completely obvious, but I just started using Python a few days ago and am completely stuck.

Comment: You need one more split on space.

Comment: Splitting on newlines gives a list of lines, then split a line on whitespace to a get a list of words on that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
input_string = ("""The cat in the hat 
Red fish blue fish """)

words = [i.split(" ") for i in  input_string.split('\n')]
```

It generates:

```
[['The', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat', ''], ['Red', 'fish', 'blue', 'fish', '']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to split on `os.linesep` (the line separator for the current OS) before you split on space. Something like:

```
import os

def input_string(input)
   words = []
   for line in input.split(os.linesep):
       words.append(line.split())
```

That will give you a list of word lists for each line.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `os.linesep`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165711/691859

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `splitlines()` as well. It will split on newlines. If you don't pass it any arguments, it will remove the newline character. If you pass it `True`, it will keep it there, but separate the lines nonetheless.

```
words = [line.split() for line in input_string.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lines = input.split('\n')
words = []
for line in lines:
    words.append(line.split(' '))
```

In english:

1. construct a list of lines, this would be analogous to reading from a file.
2. loop over each line, splitting it into a list of words
3. append the list of words to another list. this produces a list of lists.