# Want to read sequential lines in a file and do some mathematical calculation

Tags: c++, python, bash, file-io

I have a file(Data.txt), which contains data like (two column data)

```
0.105785959943        9.75133617601e+15
0.111906693211        9.03309900398e+15
0.118381569654        9.10020956844e+15
0.125231079854        9.92284743442e+15
0.132476899971        8.90313525209e+15
0.140141960337        8.94055824107e+15
0.148250518026        9.26206609674e+15
0.156828233614        8.91802025262e+15
```

The file may contain 100 lines. Let me call the values in first column as `r_i` and second column as `d_i` (`i` may change from `0` to `100`). My problem is to write a code to compute 
`C*(r_(i+1)-r_i)^3 * d_i`, where `C` is a constant.

And also I want to write these data into a new file containing 3 columns, in which the third column should be our new computed data.

How can I achieve this? Does any body know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which language are you using, `C++` or `python`? And have you tried anything already? What specific problem do you have with your current code?

Comment: @R S John: As BoBTFish said, you need specify the actual problem with your code

Comment: If `C` is constant, do you mean `C` is an array containing constants?

Comment: no C is simply 2/3 pi

Comment: @SathishKrishnan: I believe he's using `[x]` in its mathematical sense -- "x truncated to an integer".

Comment: I started to write in python. And I am very new in python.

Comment: @RSJohn I have edited the formula for clarity. Check it is still valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though 5 persons down voted my question, I found my on way to solve the problem.
Here is the code which I used. It is written in Python.

```
enter codefrom numpy import *
from math import *
import operator

f = open('Data_Genergy_26.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
# initialize some variable to be lists:
r = []
ro = []
E =[]

# scan the rows of the file stored in lines, and put the values into some variables:
for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    r.append(float(p[0]))
    ro.append(float(p[1]))
#Subtracting the current and previous item in a list
def foo(it):
    it = iter(it)
    t = it.next()
    for s in it:
        yield t, s
        t = s        
list(foo(r))
E=[x[1] - x[0] for x in foo(r)]
#print E
#Cubing all elements in a list
def cube(E):
    return [i ** 3 for i in E]
#print cube(E)
#computing total energy
z =[a*b for a,b in zip(cube(E),ro)]
z[:] = [x*4/3*pi for x in z] 
z.append(0.0) #for making r, ro, and z of same dimension
#print z     

DataOut = column_stack((r,ro,z))
savetxt('output.dat', DataOut)
```

If there is any better way to implement this please inform me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For reading the files in Python, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array). For writing output to file, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[]) {
  const double C = 1;
  double rp, dp;
  double r, d;

  std::cin >> rp >> dp;
  while (std::cin.good()) {
    std::cin >> r >> d;
    if (std::cin.good()) {
      double t = r - rp;
      double v = C * t * t * t * dp;
      std::cout << rp << " " << dp << " " << v << std::endl;
      rp = r; dp = d;
    }
  }
  std::cout << rp << " " << dp << " " << 0 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

awk is ideal for this type of calculations:

```
awk -v c="$c" '{if (s) print o, c*($1-r)^3*d;o=$0;r=$1;d=$2;s=1}' file
```

where c is a shell variable