# How to open a text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to do the following,

```
file = open('test.txt', 'w+')
item = "hello"

file.write(item)
print(file)
```

When I run this program I get the following output,

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>`

Is there a way to open and then write in the file and then save it so I can use that new file somewhere else? Even though I have something written in the file, I still get this output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python)

Comment: What do you expect `print(file)` to do?

Comment: @tim thanks i just go confused. i now understand what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open("file.txt",'r+')
lines = f.readlines()
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```