# Python Exercise "files help"

Tags: python, file, helper

So in my Python exercise I must write a program that computes and generates a report to a file with the charges for a patients hospital stay. 
The coding for the calculations were  easy enough. 
Prompt user for info, calculate info, return total charges or whatever. 
My problem is with writing a report to the file including the charges entered by user and total amount for this charges. 
I've done everything perfect, I just don't really understand how writing to files and such works...

`Infile=open("hospital_charges.txt","w")...`

Now what?
Yes obviously use the .write method. But my hospital charges file stays blank...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: This has been answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

using the write method

```
Infile.write("read documentation")
```

Documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

It is good practice to use the **with** keyword when dealing with file objects
to automatically close the file after opening it to prevent nasty errors.All of which is documented in the link given above.

Always have a look at the related tab to the right before asking questions you would be surprised how often people have had the same doubt as us before !

Comment: Very good answer! I heard that we need to close the file after performing writes, is this true?

Comment: Yes of course we should close everything after using it , to prevent nasty errors in the future.You might have issues later on if you dont close the file and edit it in the mean while.

Answer (score 0):

After writing to a file, you must close the file object to ensure data gets written to it, using

```
Infile.close()
```