# Python: Reading input from a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a text file of the format:

```
2
1 3
2 4
```

I have written a python program that asks for number of inputs and prints out the values sum .

```
n = int(raw_input())
for _ in range(n):
     a,b = map(int,raw_input().split())
     print a+b
```

But

1. How should I take input from file such that first line is number of test cases and next lines are inputs?
2. Print the output to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input comes from a file, `inp.txt`, like:

```
$ cat inp.txt 
2
1 3
2 4
```

You can use the code below, which basically reads the input file line by line, and computes the values and stores them:

```
with open("inp.txt", "r") as inp, open("out.txt", "w") as out:
    no_of_cases = int(inp.readline())
    for line in inp:
        a,b = map(int,line.split())
        out.write("%s\n" % (a + b))
```

Note that `no_of_cases` has not been used in the code anywhere above because it is redundant for this example.

This will produce the output file `out.txt` for you, with following data:

```
$ cat out.txt 
4
6
```

Answer (score 5):

1 + 2. Shell redirection.

```
$ python foo.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to make your script support both reading input from a file and reading from stdin.

```
import fileinput
num_inputs = None
for line in fileinput.input():
    if num_inputs is None:
        num_inputs = int(line)
    else:
        a,b = map(int, line.split())
        print a+b
```

This way, if you pass a filename as an argument to your script, it reads from it, else it reads from stdin.

Note that in this snippet I just read all the inputs in file after the first line, and make no real use of the `num_inputs` variable, but you can easily change that to enforce the expected number of inputs is actually read.

As to writing to a file, this is a basic python question, which has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6159900/2096752).