# Extracting data from .rsa files

Tags: python

I have a folder labeled cstruct with several with 20,000 .rsa files. In each of the files I need to extract each row that contain cys values and write the to a new file. Is there a way in python to loop through these files in this folder and extract this information?

RES SER A 102    17.74  15.2  17.22  22.0   0.52   1.4  11.89  24.5   5.85   8.6
RES HIS A 103    17.32   9.5  16.53  11.2   0.78   2.2  12.22  12.6   5.10   5.9
**RES CYS A 104     0.00   0.0   0.00   0.0   0.00   0.0   0.00   0.0   0.00   0.0**
RES LEU A 105     8.67   4.9   8.67   6.1   0.00   0.0   8.67   6.1   0.00   0.0
RES LEU A 106     5.72   3.2   5.72   4.1   0.00   0.0   5.72   4.0   0.00   0.0

Comment: what have you tried? where did you run into problems? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This might be easier to do with `grep`, depending on your other requirements...

Comment: or have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob for finding `*.rsa` files and https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re for extracting the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following Python script should get you going in the right direction:

```
import re, glob

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_output:
    for rsa_file in glob.glob(r"cstruct\*.rsa"):
        with open(rsa_file, "r") as f_input:
            f_output.write(rsa_file + "\n")
            for row in f_input:
                for cys in re.findall(r"(RES CYS\s+\w+.*?)(?= RES|\Z)", row):
                    f_output.write(cys+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the builtin open() command to open a file, and loop through it, by default Python loops over each line in the file:

```
dirName = "C:\\Wherever\\Your\\Files\\Are"
for rsafile in os.listdir(dirName):
    filepath = os.path.join(dirName, rsafile)     
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if "CYS" in line:
                print(line)
```

Depending on how your "rows" are defined, you might need to pull the relevant CYS substring out of each line after you identify the relevant lines.

Just for fun, I compared the speed of this method (if "pattern" in line) to the speed of a regex approach, re.search(".*CYS.*",line).  
For small files, on my laptop, the Python "in" operator was ~91x faster, on average (100 iterations).  
Regex re.search run time: 0.093 seconds.  
"in" operator run time:   0.001 seconds.  
That was timed with the timeit module.  The timing data include file open/close overhead, so that difference is entirely due to the matching method.

Comment: the code works nicely, but I need it to print all output to a .txt file instead of console

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python/6160082#6160082) under "Correct way to write line to file in Python", with links to documentation on `open()`.  
Use the [file object](https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-file-object)'s write method:  
    `o = open('outputFile.txt','a'); o.write(line)`  
You might have to tack on extra newlines, like: `o.write(line+'\n')`