# Python-Returning to a specific point in the code

Tags: python, list, loops, return

So I'm writing a little bit of code as a fun project that will randomly generate a subject for me to study each day. But once a subject has appeared once I don't want it to appear for the rest of the week. To do this I'm using a list. Basically, when it picks the subject it adds it to the list and the next time it checks to see if it's already on the list, and if so, I want it to return to the random number generator. How do I do this? Here's my code.

```
import random
import time
import datetime

#Subject veto list
x=[]

# Messages to instil, um, enthusiasm.
if datetime.date.today().strftime("%A") == "Monday":
    response = input("Here we go again. Are you ready? ")
elif datetime.date.today().strftime("%A") == "Tuesday" or "Wednesday" or "Thursday":
    response = input("Are you ready? ")
elif datetime.date.today().strftime("%A") == "Friday":
    response = input("Half day! Are you ready? ")
elif datetime.date.today().strftime("%A") == "Saturday" or "Sunday":
    response = input("It's the weekend! Are you ready? ")

# Random picking of subject to study. Also adds sbject to veto list for rest of week.
if response == "Yes":
        subject = random.randint(1, 7)
        print("Today you are studying...")
        time.sleep(3)
        if subject == (1):
            "Englsh" in x
            print("English")
            x.extend([English])
        elif subject == (2):
            "Irish" in x
            print("Irish")
            x.extend([Irish])
        elif subject == (3):
            "Maths" in x
            print("Maths")
            x.extend([Maths])
        elif subject == (4):
            "French" in x
            print("French")
            x.extend([French])
        elif subject == (5):
            "Physics" in x
            print("Physics")
            x.extend([Physics])
        elif subject == (6):
            "Chemistry" in x
            print("Chemistry")
            x.extend([Chemistry])
        elif subject == (7):
            "History" in x
            print("History")
            x.extend([History])
```

Comment: The problem is that the veto list won't persist. Meaning that each time you run the program, the list will be empty so all options will always be available. If you want to prevent the same option for some period of time you need to persist the information about what options you've picked recently by storing it to a database or file.

Comment: what if i were to leave the program running continuously?

Comment: That would work as long as your computer didn't restart, etc. Really though you will want to persist the information.

Comment: As @polpak stated you need to store that list to some kind of file or some "database". So the program reads from there. And than compare which subject has already been random picked. Reading and writing to files you can find here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python

Comment: Why do you have, e.g., `"History" in x`? You're wasting cycles doing comparisons and not storing the results. Also, `"something" == "x" or "y"` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: okay, i am working off a raspberry pi so it wouldnt consume too much power. But could you help me with writing it to a file? At least answer my original question and i can take it from there

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The ""History" in x" is the start of a comparison, but i wasnt sure where to go

Comment: Rewrote your code to fix all peripheral problems: http://pastebin.com/SiGSdhuC. Note that I did not address the main problem; it still does the same thing as your code. The way you would address the main problem though is by storing the subjects in a file using json.

Comment: do you have a link as to where i can learn how to do that?

Comment: @Ferex, you don't need to store state across runs in this case; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below snippet will help you.
It shows you how you can get a random element from a list.
After getting that element, the list takes out that element from the list.

```
import random

def get_random_and_pop(lst):
    value = random.choice(lst)
    lst = list(set(lst) - set([value]))
    return value,lst

lst = ['english','math','science','computer science','history']
while (len(lst)):
    v,lst = get_random_and_pop(lst)
    print v,lst
    if (len(lst) == 0):
        lst = ['english','math','science','computer science','history']
```

Comment: Thank you, but would there be a way to reset it every week say? i.e when there are no elements left?

Comment: @pzp I am not here to fix that for OP. that's another problem.

Comment: When I run the code, I get a syntax error under the v in "print v,lst" @taesu

Comment: try `print(v,lst)`, i guess you're using py3

Answer (score 2):

This function will let you choose a random thing from a list based on the weekday, without repeating* and without having to store anything between runs. The only potential issue would be if Python's PRNG was changed mid-week :P.

```
import datetime
import itertools
import random

def random_choice_per_date(iterable, date=None):
    choices = list(itertools.islice(iterable, 7))
    date = date or datetime.date.today()

    year, week, weekday = date.isocalendar()

    rand = random.Random((year, week))  # Seed PRNG with (year, week)
    rand.shuffle(choices)

    index = weekday % len(choices)

    return choices[index]
```

This is generalizable beyond dates, but I didn't want to complicate the code.

* *It **will** repeat if the iterable has less than seven items. It also only uses the first seven items at most.*

Answer (score -1):

If you put the selection algorithm in a function, and iterate that function until the returned value doesn't appear in the 'banned' list, then print the resultant non-banned value, you'd be done!

Don't actually do it that way, it would be a terrible method. simply remove the item from the options list when it's put on the banned list.. then move it back after a week.

Comment: And how would I do that? Sorry for my ineptness :(

Comment: I think there are several answers that show how, check @taesu 's answer