# What is the best way deal with large amount of fields in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, model

Anyone can suggest me any good solution? The problem:

There is spreadsheets with data and i need to create a model with more than 40 of indexable fields (maybe even more in future) is there anything to help me to avoid hand work to define this fields manually? The fields are some kind of chemical parameters with long names, i guess need to create aliases to access them easily.

UPD: googled for a hour, can't find anything. Maybe i'll just create model dynamically from configuration stored in YAML or JSON file? Or use Postgres JSON field? But i feel it's gonna be disaster to make admin interface to work with it.

Comment: You can write *models.py* by making use of [`file.write()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6159912/1925257) method.

Comment: i can make it programmatically using meta classes but it would be difficult to manage it.

Comment: Yeah, that might work, too. But still you'll need to read the spreadsheet or JSON file to be able to set fields on a model. Considering that, you're better off with using `file.write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after the accurate research of the subject i found few options:

- Store main part of parameter in Postgres as a columns and the rest in mongodb and use proxy model/custom manager to retrieve this data when required.
- Postgres HSTORE (but only for string fields) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-hstorefield
- And Entity Attribute Value Model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model
- Dynamically creating models from JSON/YAML configuration.