# How to data print data to CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv

I created a python program to provide a diff file. Wanted to know what the best way to send the results of the diff into a .csv would be

Here's my code,

```
import difflib

file1 = "swiss1.csv"
file2 = "swiss2.csv"

diff = difflib.ndiff(open(file1).readlines(),open(file2).readlines())

for line in diff:
    if line[0] in ["+", "-"]:
        print line
```

Rather than print to the terminal I would like to print it to a CSV file. Thoughts?

Comment: 'write to file python' this is the google search term for your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python)

Comment: @Ectropy that doesn't work. I'm trying to print the diff data from the program. I'm not trying to write data in f.write()

Comment: So heres my origional code, 

import difflib
import csv
file1 = "swiss1.csv"
file2 = "swiss2.csv"

diff = difflib.ndiff(open(file1).readlines(),open(file2).readlines())

for line in diff:
    if line[0] in ["+", "-"]:
        print line

Answer (score 0):

```
import difflib
import csv
file1 = "swiss1.csv"
file2 = "swiss2.csv"

diff = difflib.ndiff(open(file1).readlines(),open(file2).readlines())
f = open('changes.csv','w')
for line in diff:
    if line[0] in ["+", "-"]:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```