# Writing data to a file-python

Tags: python

Here is my task:
Write a sign up program for an after school club, it should ask the user for the following details and store them in a file: First Name, Last Name, Gender and Form.

Here is my code so far:

```
f= open("test.txt","w+")
first_name = input("Enter your First name>>>> ")
last_name = input("Enter your Last name>>>> ")
gender = input("Enter your gender>>>> ")

with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(first_name, second_name, gender)
```

I have created the file but when I try to write to it I get an error saying

```
myfile.write(first_name, last_name, gender)
TypeError: write() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)"
```

Comment: because write only takes one argument (just like the error says). you need to concatenate your `first_name second_name gender` together

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the syntax for write() method −

```
fileObject.write( str )
```

This means you need to concat your arguments into one string.

For example:

```
myfile.write(first_name + second_name + gender)
```

Or you can use format as well:

```
fileObject.write('{} {} {}'.format(first_name, second_name, gender))
```

Comment: It can also be done with `myfile.write(' '.join((first_name, second_name, gender)))` It's more useful if you just have a list of things without a particular meaning, like a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

as the write function takes a single string argument, you have to append the strings into one and then write them to a file. You can't pass 3 different strings at once to `myfile.write()`

```
final_str = first_name + " " + second_name + " "+gender
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(final_str)
```