# How to add line break in a text file after each word

Tags: python, text

I have a text file with this contents "one two three four" and I want to create a new text file with one word for each line, like this:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I came up with this code:

```
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split('\n'):
        print word
```

It prints each word in new line, so my question how I can write these words in new file that have one word each line?

Comment: what's the difference between "each word in new line" and "one word each line"? seems like your code does that and is what you're looking for

Comment: what i am trying to do, is to create text file that have one column, and each line have just one word form the old file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close to the proper answer but you need to split the line differently. `for line in f` already reads the file newline-by-newline. So just do a normal split to break the line using whitespace characters. This will usually split text files into words successfully.

You can handle multiple files in a `with` statement, which is very convenient for scripts like yours. Writing to a file is a lot like `print` with a few small differences. `write` is straightforward, but doesn't do newlines automatically. There's a couple other ways to write data to a file and seek through it, and I highly recommend you learn a bit more about them by reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Below is your code with the changes applied. Be sure to take a look and understand why the changes were needed:

```
with open('words.txt','r') as f, open('words2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
       for word in line.split():
           f2.write(word + '\n')
```