# how do I write the output of this code in a different file in python

Tags: python

```
import csv

with open('motion 2017-11-13 13-34-25.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
 for row in reader:
   if row['event'] == "location":
    print(row['time'], row['event'], row['latitude'], row['longitude'] ) #column fields want to print
  else: 
    if row['event'] == "motion":
    print(row['time'], row['event'], row['earthAcceleration.x'], 
   row['earthAcceleration.y'], row['earthAcceleration.z'] ) #column fields i want
  else:
    print(row['time'], row['event'] )
```

I am using if else to display certain values according to action, now from 3 cases one case will be true and value will be printed, but I want to print that output in a csv file(write into it)
Sample input

time event acceleration.x rotation.x latitude longitude

2017-11-20 11:22:21 153 location -0.901233 0.8397 1.121  23.22

2017-11-20 11:22:31 153 motion -0.541233 0.4327   2.22 30.22

2017-11-20 11:22:21 153 start -0.901233 0.8397 2.22 5.22

Sample output

time event latitude longitude

2017-11-20 11:22:21 153 location 1.121  23.22

So according to the condition(event) the row will be fetched if it is motion,location or anything else, the output should be that row and I want all those rows with that event to write into a csv file.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and post a sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have fixed for them

Comment: not quite. Still some issues

Comment: Whoops, feel free to fix whilst I write my answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre fixed it let me know if you need anything else

Comment: `csvfile.write('Your text \n')`

Comment: correct to: `with open('motion 2017-11-13 13-34-25.csv', 'a') as csvfile:`