# Python writing in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to write  `(i['src'])` in a `file.txt` that I do not arrive ?

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

a = requests.get('domaine.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('iframe')
for i in links:
    print(i['src'])
```

Comment: Can you please clarify more on this line *How to write  `(i['src'])` in a `file.txt` that I do not arrive ?*

Comment: thank you for your answer, I do not want to print, but stored in a text file ( .write ) sorry for my english i use google translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these answers:
[Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

a = requests.get('http://domaine.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('iframe')
f = open('file.txt', 'a')
for i in links:
    f.write(str(i['src']) + '\n')
```

Output of file.txt:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-M6RJ9CB
```