# csv.writer: Need to run loop, but it stops after one iteration

Tags: python, loops, csv, time

I am attempting to pull from an API. The file runs fine if coded to run a single time. But I am having issues when coded to run once every minute (`x[5]==0`). The program does pull from the API (as evidenced by `<print(i)>`), but doesn't seem to interact with the CSV file.

```
import csv
import time

c = open("file.csv", "a")
w = csv.writer(c, lineterminator="\n")

while True:
  x = time.localtime()
    if x[5]==0:

      client.request(r)
      print(i)
      for i in r.response["list"]
      w.writerow([i["list_item1"], i["list_item2"]])
```

The program will loop through and `print`, but it will not write to `"file.csv"`. I attempted to get the CSV file to `close`.

```
      client.request(r)
      print(i)
      for i in r.response["list"]
      w.writerow([i["list_item1"], i["list_item2"]])
      c.close()
```

With this, the program will loop through once, write to `"file.csv"` once, then shut down with the following error:

```
    w.writerow([i["list_item1"], i["list_item2"]])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I tried adding a `with` statement in a few places, but I couldn't get anything to work.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You get that error because you close the file and don't reopen it.

Comment: Isn't c = open("file.csv", "a") supposed to make it re-open every time?

Comment: please use the answer from here when it comes to opening files [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)  you can follow the same struction with using `with open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks fine. you don't need `c.close()`

just add `c.flush()` at the end of your code .
as you have infinite while loop you just need to flush data into you csv file.

hope this fixes your issue.

```
 Note flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use flush() followed by os.fsync() to ensure this behavior.
```

read this [file.flush](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush)

Comment: Bingo! Thank you!

Comment: It worked without os.fsync(), but I'll add it for good measure.