# Output file in Python

Tags: python

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy()
ssh.connect('hostname', username='test', password='123')
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
with open('path.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line
        for filename in sftp.listdir(line):
            if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.file')  or filename.endswith('.xml'):
                check_1 = filename
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('hostname')
                result1 = stdout.read().decode().splitlines()           
                std1in, std1out, std1err = ssh.exec_command('python -V')
                result2 = std1out.read().decode().splitlines()              
                output_check = '{0:>25} {1:>45} {2:>30}'.format(filename,result1,result2)
                print output_check
                file = open("check.txt","a")
                file.write(output_check)
                file.close()
```

> while executing the script my code is giving output which i expected, 
>   but when i tried to print the output in text file. Alignment is not
>   providing in correct format in check.txt file
>
> Script output
>
> ```
>         /home/test1/check.txt        server1       python3.0       
>         /home/test1/check1.txt       server1       python3.0
> ```
>
> check.txt file is writing as
>
> ```
>       /home/test1/check.txt        server1       python3.0  /home/test1/check1.txt        server1       python3.0
> ```

Comment: How to make alignment exactly like script output in check.txt file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Paramiko. It's only about writing lines to a local file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy()
ssh.connect('hostname', username='test', password='123')
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
with open('path.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line
        for filename in sftp.listdir(line):
            if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.file')  or filename.endswith('.xml'):
                check_1 = filename
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('hostname')
                result1 = stdout.read().decode().splitlines()           
                std1in, std1out, std1err = ssh.exec_command('python -V')
                result2 = std1out.read().decode().splitlines()              
                output_check = '{0:>25} {1:>45} {2:>30}'.format(filename,result1,result2)
                print output_check
                file = open("check.txt","a")
                file.write(output_check,'\n')
                file.close()
```

Comment: Please, do not answer duplicate questions, vote them to be closed instead.