# Value error raised when I try constructing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
Prediction_final = np.argmax(results, axis=0)[0]
output = pd.DataFrame(Prediction_final.T)
```

The code above takes a numpy array, finds the argmax, and then converts it into a Pandas data frame for export. Unfortunately, a value error is raised when I do this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svm_own.py", line 106, in <module>
    output = pd.DataFrame(Prediction_final.T)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 404, in __init__
raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
```

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

I've been trying to debug this, but have not found why this error occurs. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll get that error if you try to give `DataFrame` a single number, which it looks like you are doing.

Comment: np.argmax returns a single value, not an array, which is not a valid object to pass to the DataFrame constructor.  I don't really understand what your goal is.  Could you post the nature of `results` and your desired output?

Comment: If you really want a df with only 1 cell then just wrap with `[]` :`pd.DataFrame([Prediction_final.T])`

Comment: if your goal is to then write that single value to a file, then just follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) instead of using `df.to_csv()`

Comment: Looks like the [0] was the issue. I wanted all the values, an accidentally took a single value. Thanks for the solution. @chrisz your answer worked, If you post it as a solution, I'll accept it.