# which variable is being plotted (which line of the code)?

Tags: python

what variable is being plotted and where should modify my code to store the data in a text file.

there are so many def function that I could not find the line that prints the variable.

the code in the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P82abYvA-yv_oAGLrzhlkD8vEuqippWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide minimal code where code is not working or any doubtful statement. Rather then attach full document. Please learn how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: it is not a duplicate and the I think a person will to need to see the whole code to find the line to plot the variable.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write some data in a text file it would go something like this:

```
f = open("guru99.txt", "a")
data = "some data"
f.write(data)
```

Comment: I know how to save the data, but were in my code those lines need to be?

Comment: the data of the function is contained add by the function `read_frame()`, more specifically `frame=np.array(d.data)` so I would suggest to add d.data to your file

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the answer contributed by @FlyingZipper, if you're looking to write multiple elements from an array into your text file, you can do this using a loop:

```
f = open("guru99.txt", "a")
data = ["1", "2", "3"]
for x in data:
    f.write(x)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I know how to save the data, but were in my code those lines need to be?