# Write mode "a" in python

Tags: python, arrays

when i use the write mode:

```
d = open("test.txt","a")
d.write(letter)
```

it always appends the text at the end everytime i write someting into the file.
My question is, how to write as new line like this:

```
a
b
c
```

Currently it writes:

```
abc
```

Using \n does not work unfortunally...

Thanks so much

Comment: What code do you have already that writes to the file object `d`?

Comment: `/n` is not `\n`.

Comment: i just edited the code

Comment: ...and how are you creating the variable `letter`?

Comment: So... are you using `\n` or `/n`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add a newline character after the letter:

```
d.write(letter + '\n')
```

Or if you are using Python 3 or if you `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2:

```
print(letter, file=d)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file), you can do :

```
with open('test.txt', 'a') as d:

    d.write('YOURTEXT\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The new-line character **"\n"** works fine with "a" (append) option for writing files in python.

Example:

```
d = open(filepath, "a")
d.write("hello")
d.write("\n")
d.write("hello again")
d.close()
```

o/p:

```
hello
hello again
```

OR -> To append text from next line of the existing text of file.

```
d.write('\n')
d.write("hello" + '\n')
```