# Printing the output of a new file in a clean and orderly format

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to use code to be able to create a file called output.txt.

However, when I print the following code and then look in the actual .txt file, it prints it all on one line, which is NOT what I want.

```
 file2.write("*******************************************")
 file2.write("                   ""TICKET REPORT""                   ")
 file2.write("")
 file2.write("There are 6 tickets in the database.")
 file2.write("")
 file2.write("Maximum Ticket price is $179.99.")
 file2.write("Minimum Ticket price is $49.99.")
 file2.write("Average Ticket Price is $149.99.")
 file2.write("")
 file2.write("Thank you for using our ticket system!")
 file2.write("")
 file2.write("*******************************************")
 file2.close()
```

I want the text to print line-by-line as it shows below. Keep in mind, I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `'\n'` at the end of the line **or** the other solution is:

```
lines = [line0, line1, .... ]
fo = open("foo.txt", "rw+")
fo.writelines(lines)
```