# Save formated contents of file to another file in Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am opening a `.tsv` file and changing its contents using some regexp:

```
with open("test.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        #print(line[2])
        match = re.search('(\w*[А-Я]\w*[А-Я]\w*)|(\d)|(%|$|€)', line[2])
        if match:
            print(line[2])
```

How can I save the modified contents to another `.tsv` file?

Update:
I need to save full line, not only line[2]

Comment: So just use another context manager within this one - this time open `with open("test.tsv", "w") as f:` and write to it.

Comment: Also, I think that you would want to escape the `$` like `\$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using below code.

```
import csv

with open("test.tsv", 'wt') as tsvfile:
    tsv_reader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    tsv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
    for line in tsvreader:
        #print(line[2])
        match = re.search('(\w*[А-Я]\w*[А-Я]\w*)|(\d)|(%|$|€)', line[2])
        if match:
            print(line[2])
            tsv_writer.writerow(line[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```py
with open("test.tsv") as tsvfile, open("new_test.tsv", "a") as new_tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        #print(line[2])
        match = re.search('(\w*[А-Я]\w*[А-Я]\w*)|(\d)|(%|$|€)', line[2])
        if match:
            new_tsvfile.write(line[2] + "\n")
```

should work, but I didn't test it.

[*Reference answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160082/865175)

Comment: I'm getting error "write() argument must be str, not list", i guees because line is a list

Comment: Does `new_tsvfile.write("\t".join(line[2]) + "\n")` work?