# How can I add functions in a text file

Tags: python

I have done a program with 4 functions, now I have to add the results produced by the functions into a text file from python. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: I want to know how to add a function in a text file not a string

Comment: There is no difference, what have you tried/researched?

Comment: An error is shown ... function object not iterable

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and read [ask], although your question is still a duplicate.

Comment: Using a function in place of String....error comes saying function object not iterable

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

open a text file where you want to save and put it in the write mode

```
def func1(a, b):
    return a+b
def func2(a, b):
    return a-b
def func3(a, b):
    return a*b
def func4(a, b):
    return a/b

txt_write = open('file_name', 'w+')
txt_write.writelines(func1(2,6))
txt_write.writelines(func2(7,1))
txt_write.writelines(func3(6,3))
txt_write.writelines(func4(9,3))
txt_write.close()
```

use `writelines` to write in the text file. Don't forget to close the file.

Comment: It's an error saying function object is not iterable

Comment: oops I forgot to pass params in function

Comment: ...I don't have any parameters in my program?

Comment: then you don't have to pass it and remove all function params

Comment: can you give your code here so I can look through it?