# How to add a line in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

I was learning about files in python 3, making a .txt and trying to write things, and I wanted to write in line:

```
f=open("file.txt","w")
list=['hello',''how are you?']
for a in list:
        f.write(a)
f.close()
```

This is what I expected was:

```
Hello
How are you?
```

But the program write:

```
HelloHow are you?
```

How do I add a new line in the program?

Comment: Use \n to separate lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new line special character.

So here it would look like:

```
f=open("file.txt","w")
list=['hello','how are you?']
for a in list:
        f.write(a + "\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write to the file in this way.

```
file.write(your_string + '\n')
```