# How can I get my python code to save some scraped numbers every day onto some file?

Tags: python, database

I am currently working on a simple COVID-19 tracker for a specific area. I am trying to find a way to make my code, which reruns daily and scrapes from a table from another site, write some data (like deaths, cases, etc) along with a day number to some kind of text or database.

However, I am not completely sure how I would go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your question about how to schedule running your code once a day? Or is it about how to write to a file? Or both?

Comment: Metropolis my code already automatically runs once a day. I just don't really know how exactly I should make it write my data to a file/db.

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file