# How can you write to a text file in python 3?

Tags: python

Could someone please explain why this code won't write to a text file?
I run the code but a text file is not created and also cannot be opened using f.open("data.txt","r")

```
f = open("data.txt", "w+")
n = 1
s = 0
for n in range(1, 999999):
    s  += 1/n**2
    print(s, end="\r")
x = s*6
pisquare = math.sqrt(x)
f.write("Pi is ", pisquare)
f.close()
```

Comment: you should take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

Comment: Does @penguin's suggestion answer your question? [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: If I run your program I get an error which tells me why it's failing to write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
f = open("data.txt", "w+")
n = 1
s = 0
for n in range(1, 999999):
    s  += 1/n**2
    print(s, end="\r")
x = s*6
pisquare = math.sqrt(x)
f.write("Pi is " + str(pisquare))
f.close()
```

I am able to create the text file. Please check for it in your current directory. But if I understand your code correctly, this is what you are looking for -

```
import math

n = 1
s = 0
with open("data.txt", "w+") as f:
    for n in range(1, 9999):
        s  += 1/n**2
        print(s, end="\r")
        x = s*6
        pisquare = math.sqrt(x)
        f.write(" Pi is " + str(pisquare) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to open and write to a file is as follow:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(f'Pi is {pisquare}')
```

We use the context manager `with` so the file closes automatically when done with `.write()`. This prevents memory corruption when your program exits prematurely I believe.

However, as you have probably noticed, your problem comes from this line:

```
f.write("Pi is ", pisquare)
```

You are giving `.write()` two arguments rather than one string.

Comment: The solution that I would do is either f-strings or `f.write("Pi is %s" % pisquare")`.

Comment: this doesn't explain why the file isn't created at all, though, and the OP is manually closing the file anyway.

Comment: I can't think of an explanation for it, especially without an error code.