# I want to direct my python output to a specific text file from inside the code

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, output

I am printing my code in this format given below.
I want to redirect this output to a file called test.txt. How can I do that?

```
for row in output:
        print(format_string.format(*row)
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file  Also you're missing a parenthesis

Comment: it would really helpful if you could also help with my other question