# How can I save the results of print() into a .txt file in a directory?

Tags: python, printing, spacy, corpus, lemmatization

I want to lemmatize a corpus of 24 .txt files (`dir1`) and save them in `dir2`. I want to write the output of `print(word.lemma_, end=" ")`  in `dir2`. This is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import re
import nltk
import spacy
import sys
sp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> dir1=("corpus")
>>> dir2=("corpus2")
for txt in os.listdir(dir1):
    file=open(dir1+"/"+txt, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    for line in file:
        sentence=sp(line)
        for word in sentence:
            print(word.lemma_, end=" ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to write line to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Comment: The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has an optional *`file=`* argument that will send the output to one. In addition, the `contextlib` module has a [`redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) function that can be applied to all the `print()` calls within a block of code.