# How to edit a text file in a folder?

Tags: python

This is the file set up:

```
text_file.csv
Folder----code.py
```

What I want do do is have `code.py` write `"bob"` in `text_file.csv`.

(Note: a `.csv` file is just a text file.)

Comment: csv and txt are not the same thing. for csv use `csv.writer()` and for txt use `fileID.write()`. You may also need `os.chdir()` to get to the file.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file/6160082#6160082

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'editing' a file? Overwrite a few sections? Append? Truncate to zero? That will determine which mode you `open()` in, and whether you `read()` before `write()`ing.

Comment: While CSV files *are* text files, their contents is formatted in a [certain way](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html) — which you need to follow if you want it to be (or remain) valid. I strongly suggest you use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read and write them.

Comment: @Wups: The answers to the linked question don't really apply to CSV-formatted text files.

Comment: @Joseph: What exactly do you mean by "edit a text file"?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: csv file is not equal as text file, `csv` is a `comma-separated-values` file, and it is formatted in a different way, you should watch out for these things, for more informations, visit the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

if you want to write the content you can use the `built-in` open function:

```
open(Path,mode).write(content)
```

if you want to overwrite the content use `'w'` mode:

```
open("..\\text_file.csv","w").write("bob")
```

if you want to add it append it, you can use the `'a'` mode:

```
open("..\\text_file.csv",'a').write("bob")
```

but if you want to add it as a newline, you should add a `'\n'` in fromt of the `"bob"`(the text you want to put in):

```
open("..\\text_file.csv","a").write('\n'+"bob") #adding a newline to 'bob'
```

Comment: You probably want to add `\n` to those strings.  `file.write` doesn't add one automatically.

Comment: Yes, thanks for letting me know, I updated the answer.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, I've tried stuff like that so many different times but it has never worked until now, thanks.

Comment: you should mark it too, could help other people.