# Trouble loading large excel file (Python)

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I am trying to load a large `.xlsx` file using `OpenPyXL`, while loading a 80 MB .xlsx file my entire 8 GB of memory is getting full

[image]

Excel file has 4 sheets with 800 000 rows.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Record.xlsx')

def process(ws):
    '''
    Read all rows of a worksheet
    '''
    data = []
    for a, c, f, k in zip(ws['A'], ws['C'], ws['F'], ws['K']):
        data.append([a, c, f, k])

    return data

ws1 = wb.worksheets[0] # Sheet 1
data1 = process(ws1)
ws2 = wb.worksheets[1] # Sheet 2
data2 = process(ws2)
ws3 = wb.worksheets[2] # Sheet 3
data3 = process(ws3)
ws4 = wb.worksheets[3] # Sheet 4
data4 = process(ws4)
```

Why while loading 80 MB of excel file 8 GB of memory is not enough?

Comment: Can you show us your code, it looks like something is causing a memory leak maybe ?

Comment: is it really that you have only these 2 rows in your code? may be parsing  later does give you the issue? I never had problems reading; and for parsing use generators(yield)

Comment: Have you tried `read_only = True` to use [read only mode](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest Way To Run Through 50k Lines of Excel File in OpenPYXL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638117/fastest-way-to-run-through-50k-lines-of-excel-file-in-openpyxl)

Comment: @BcK I have updated the code

Comment: @Colin While setting `read_only = True`, I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'iter_cols'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `read_only = True` argument to use read only mode, as described [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html).

Comment: While setting `read_only = True`, I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'iter_cols'`

Comment: @User Read-only mode doesn't support iterating through columns, only rows. There's a suggested way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584317/8142697).

Comment: I used `for row in ws.rows` to access the rows and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)