# Fast printing of a list in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, int

I need a fast way to print a list instead of it taking ages to print my sometimes over 100000 long list with

```
print "[%s]" % ", ".join(map(str, primes))
```

or

```
str(primes).strip('[]')
```

i need something faster, any idea. 
Also the list contains 100% integers

Comment: Do you now want the list with or without the square brackets? The first example manually adds them, but the second one manually removes them...

Comment: Without, though the speed is what i care about

Comment: Probably the slowest part is the print itself, or to be more exact, the time your terminal emulator needs to process the output. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3857052/4464570