# Wy can't Powershell display a string when i use stdout in Python?

Tags: python, powershell

It runs fine in VS Code, but in powershell it does prompt user input but without displaying the string in "stdout".
Here is the sample piece of code:

```
import sys


def get_int():
    sys.stdout.write("Enter number(s). ")
    return map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())


def get_float():
    sys.stdout.write("Enter number(s). ")
    return map(float, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())


def get_list_of_int():
    sys.stdout.write("Enter numbers followed by space. ")
    return list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()))


def get_string():
    sys.stdout.write("Enter string. ")
    return sys.stdin.readline().strip()


a, b, c, d = get_int()
e, f, g = get_float()
arr = get_list_of_int()
str = get_string()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `input()` ?

Comment: To speed up the program.

Comment: 0x5961736972: can you please provide a source backing your statment? AFAIK `input()` doesn't _slow_ your script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3857052/13597101

Comment: The question that you linked is unrelated to `input` slowering your script, it actually talks about output. I won't post any further comments here, but I definitely advise you to read about [python's build-in `input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) because you've a misconception about what it does and  doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't Powershell display a string when i use stdout in Python?

Because the `stdout` device interface may buffer writes to it, so either run python in unbuffered mode:

```
PS C:\> python -u script.py
```

or explicitly flush the buffer before reading `stdin`:

```py
def get_int():
    sys.stdout.write("Enter number(s). ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())
```

or you can [replace `sys.stdout` with a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) that does it for you:

```py
class Unbuffered(object):
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def writelines(self, datas):
       self.stream.writelines(datas)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)

sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)

# this will now flush automatically before calling stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write("Enter something: ")
numbers = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())
```