# PL/SQL local variables dump

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to get a string containing a list of the local variables names and their values at any point in time to aid in debugging (i.e. add to a row in the log table of the database as a text string)?

Comment: Certainly it is somehow possible because there is debuging mode in Oracle DB, but I suggest you to use some IDE like PL/SQL Developer or Oracle SQL developer which have built in debugging window which allows you to do exactly this - to set break point, to step in, to see current values of variables, etc.

Comment: Personally I don't use debuggers but logging. In PL/SQL scope that's a dedicated log table, small amount of supporting PL/SQL code, conditional compilation and a lot of nicely formatted ["print"-statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/189562/272735).

Comment: Is there a generic way to grab all local variables to log them

Comment: Have you looked at the DBMS_DEBUG PL/SQL Package?  Could possibly help, but too involved to discuss here.  See the PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference (assuming 11g)

Comment: Do you have example of your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

`DBMS_DEBUG` can inspect PL/SQL variables, but it requires that the running session suspend and that a second session attach to it to perform the inspection.

I've thought about creating an API to spawn a second session (via DBMS_SCHEDULER) which would stop the calling session, inspect it, restart it, and report back.

That'd be very involved and I'm not sure it'd be a supported use case of `DBMS_DEBUG`.

Short of that, there is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Is not possible to obtain a String with debug information, however using Sql Developer (Oracle free tool) you can DEBUG your pl/sql as usual likewise any other debug tool for another language including the VALUE for any variable.

This is taken from its documentation:

[image: Sqldeveloper debug overview]

HTH

Comment: This answer should be awared by more upvotes. Thanks.