# Getting a new error: NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/.../.DS_Store'

Tags: python, pdf, operating-system, pypdf

My code was working until yesterday, January 31, 2022. But today, Feb. 1, 2022, it sudden

Here's the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/folder/code/3.cut_PDF.py", line 19, in 
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/.../Riskalyze/02.01.22/.DS_Store'

Here's my code:

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

today_date = date.today().strftime("%m.%d.%y")
print(today_date)

mypath_folder = '/Users/.../Riskalyze/' + today_date + '/'

onlyfolder = [f for f in listdir(mypath_folder)]
print(onlyfolder)

pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
for folder in onlyfolder:
    mypath = mypath_folder + folder
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    print(onlyfiles)
    i = 0
    if folder == "#Model":
        model_name = []
        print(type(model_name))
        for file in onlyfiles:
            file_name = file.rsplit(".")[0]
            file_name = file_name.split("Portfolio")[0]
            file_name = file_name + "Portfolio"
            model_name.append(file_name)
            print("model name:", model_name)
    else:
        pass
    for file in onlyfiles:
        print(file)
        mypath_new = mypath + '/' + file
        print(mypath_new)
        pdfFileObj = open(mypath_new, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
        i += 1
        print("i:", i)

pdfOutputFile = open('/Users/.../Riskalyze/MergedFiles/MergedFiles_' + today_date + '.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
pdfFileObj.close()
pdfOutputFile.close()
print(model_name)
```

Comment: This issue was resolved by updating the chromedriver in my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

([`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard Python library is much more handy to use than `os` and `os.path`, I suggest you give it a try)

As for your problem,

```py
onlyfolder = [f for f in listdir(mypath_folder)]
```

is wrong.

The [doc for `os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) :

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.

It lists the content of a directory, not just the directories in it. So you have a filename in your `onlyfolder` list, so that later when you do `isfile(join(mypath, f))` it tries to access `f` (the file name) in the `mypath` directory, which happens to be a file (`.DS_Store`).

You could have found it yourself by [using a **debugger**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) or simply [**printf-debugging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189562/what-is-the-proper-name-for-doing-debugging-by-adding-print-statements).

Comment: The issue was resolved by updating the chromedriver. I will definitely look into pathlib. Thank you so much for your help!